# How to create Tabs in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to create tabs at the bottom of the screen, which has to be there through out the application and a list needs to be displayed above. Please help...

Comment: real tabs or bottom bar buttons??? can you explain more about functionality ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to this below link:

[Advanced UI Components](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-advanced-buttons-fields-and-managers/ta-p/488276)

Here you can get one zip file. In that see the `UIExamplePillButtonScreen` and understand it. If you want the tabs for all screens then

Write the code in one class(Ex: TabPannel.java) which `extends Field` and add this to any screen like:

```
setStatus(new TabPannel());
```

This below link also helpful to you:

[Tab bar in blackberry without ToolBarManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942225/tab-bar-in-blackberry-without-toolbarmanager/8967671#8967671)

Enough.