# TabField at the bottom of screen not producing click event at all tabs other then 1st tab in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, tabbar

I am working in a BlackBerry application in which I need to use the tabs at the bottom.

Earlier I had already used the tabs but at the top of the screen. To place the tabs at the bottom of the screen I used the `sublayout()` method. But the side effects of this is I can't use the `display(index)` method now. Every time when i click on any of the tab, only 1st tab get selected. When i hide the `sublayout()` method than everything works fine.

This is my code that I am using:

**TabControl.java**

```java
public class TabControl extends MainScreen{
    public static int tabHeight = 0;
    public static TabField mTabField = null;
    public static Bitmap BACKGROUND_IMAGE = Bitmap
    .getBitmapResource("Background_Superhero.png");
    private UiApplication uiApp = UiApplication.getUiApplication();
    private UiEngine ui = Ui.getUiEngine();
    private int displayHieght;
    public TabControl(BuddyListField buddyList) {
        super(MainScreen.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL);
    }
    public void addFields() {
        try {
            mTabField = new TabField(this);
            add(mTabField);
            HomeTab home = new HomeTab();
            mTabField.addTab(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("home_tab.png"), home,
                    Field.FOCUSABLE);
            SettingTab setting = new SettingTab();
            mTabField.addTab(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("Setting_tab.png"), setting,
                    Field.FOCUSABLE);
            AboutTab about = new AboutTab();
            mTabField.addTab(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("abouttab.png"), about,
                    Field.FOCUSABLE);

            mTabField.setDefault(Constant.SETTING_TAB_INDEX);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e+"=-====>>TabControl");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    protected boolean keyDown(int keycode, int time) {
        if (keycode == 1769472) {
            // escape pressed
            return true;
        }
        return super.keyDown(keycode, time);
    }
}
```

**TabField.java**

```java
public class TabField extends VerticalFieldManager {


    private static Bitmap tabBackGroundImage = Bitmap
    .getBitmapResource("tab_bar.png");
    private Background CONTROL_NORMAL_BG = BackgroundFactory
    .createBitmapBackground(tabBackGroundImage);
    private Background CONTROL_ACTIVE_BG = BackgroundFactory
    .createSolidBackground(Color.SILVER);

    public static int indexValue = 0;
    private static int mCurrentIndex = 0;
    private int mDefault = 0;

    private Field mCurrentField = null;
    private Vector mTabFields = new Vector();
    private MainScreen _mainscreen = null;
    private HorizontalFieldManager mTabController = new HorizontalFieldManager();

    private UiApplication uiApp = UiApplication.getUiApplication();
    private UiEngine ui = Ui.getUiEngine();
    private int tabHieght;
    private int displayHieght;


    public TabField(MainScreen mainscreen) {
        super(MainScreen.USE_ALL_HEIGHT);
        _mainscreen = mainscreen;
        displayHieght = Display.getHeight();

        add(mTabController);
        SeparatorField separatorField = new SeparatorField();
        separatorField.setBackground(CONTROL_ACTIVE_BG);
        add(separatorField);

    }

    public void setDefault(int index) {
        mDefault = index;
        if (mDefault <= mTabFields.size() - 1) {
            display(mDefault);
        }
    }

    public void display(int index) {
        VirtualKeyboard virtKbd = _mainscreen.getVirtualKeyboard();
        if(virtKbd != null)
            virtKbd.setVisibility(VirtualKeyboard.RESTORE);

        try {
            if (mCurrentField != null) {
                if (mCurrentField instanceof TabFieldItem) {
                    ((TabFieldItem) mCurrentField).onUnSelected();
                }
                delete(mCurrentField);
            }
            mCurrentField = (Field) mTabFields.elementAt(index);
            add(mCurrentField);
            mCurrentField.setFocus();

            if (mCurrentField instanceof TabFieldItem) {
                ((TabFieldItem) mCurrentField).onSelected();
            }

            setDirty(false);
            BitmapField mCurrentBG = (BitmapField) mTabController
            .getField(mCurrentIndex);

            mCurrentBG.setBackground(CONTROL_NORMAL_BG);
            mCurrentBG.setBitmap(getOnUnFocusImg(mCurrentIndex));
            BitmapField mBG = (BitmapField) mTabController.getField(index);
            mBG.setBackground(CONTROL_ACTIVE_BG);
            mBG.setBitmap(getOnFocusImg(index));
            mCurrentIndex = index;
            if(virtKbd != null)
                virtKbd.setVisibility(VirtualKeyboard.HIDE);
            if (indexValue == 3) {


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: In TabField--->display() "
                    + e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void addTab(Bitmap aBitmap, final Field aTabField, long style) {
        BitmapField lButton = null;
        if (style == Field.FOCUSABLE) {
            final BitmapField focusbleButton = new BitmapField(aBitmap,
                    Field.FOCUSABLE) {
                protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
                    if (aTabField == null) {
                        return false; 
                    }
                    indexValue = getIndex();
                    display(indexValue);
                    return true;
                }

                protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
                    if (indexValue == getIndex()) {
                        graphics.setBackgroundColor(Color.SILVER);
                        graphics.clear();
                    }
                    super.paint(graphics);
                }

                public void setSpace(int hSpace, int vSpace) {

                    super.setSpace(hSpace, vSpace);
                }
            };
            focusbleButton.setBackground(CONTROL_NORMAL_BG);
            setlButtonSpace(focusbleButton);
            lButton = focusbleButton;
        } else {
            lButton = new BitmapField(aBitmap);
        }
        /*if (WallpaperMainScreen.tabHeight == 0)
            WallpaperMainScreen.tabHeight = lButton.getBitmapHeight();*/
        mTabController.add(lButton);
        mTabFields.addElement(aTabField);

        if (mDefault == mTabFields.size() - 1 && aTabField != null) {
            display(mDefault);
        }
    }

    //SUBLAYOUT METHOD USED TO BRING THE TABBAR AT THE BOTTOM OF THE SCREEN---------------
    protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
        super.sublayout(maxWidth, maxHeight);
        tabHieght = mTabController.getHeight();
        int y = displayHieght - tabHieght;
        setPositionChild(mTabController, 0, y);
    }


    private void setlButtonSpace(BitmapField lButton) {
        int tabWidth = Display.getWidth() / 3;
        int imagewidth = lButton.getBitmapWidth();
        int imageheight = lButton.getBitmapHeight();
        int hPaddingValue = (tabWidth - imagewidth) / 2;
        int vPaddingValue = (tabWidth - imageheight) / 7;
        lButton.setSpace(hPaddingValue + 1, vPaddingValue);
    }

    private Bitmap getOnFocusImg(int index) {
        Bitmap image = null;
        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            image = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("home_tab.png");
            break;
        case 1:
            image = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("Setting_tab.png");
            break;
        case 2:
            image = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("about_tab.png");
            break;
        /*case 3:
            image = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("exit_tab.png");
            break;
*/
        }
        return image;
    }

    private Bitmap getOnUnFocusImg(int currentIndex) {
        Bitmap image = null;
        switch (currentIndex) {
        case 0:
            image = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("home_tab.png");
            break;
        case 1:
            image = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("Setting_tab.png");
            break;
        case 2:
            image = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("about_tab.png");
            break;
        /*case 3:
            image = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("exit_tab.png");
            break;*/
        }
        return image;

    }


    protected boolean keyChar(char ch, int status, int time) {
        if (mCurrentField != null && mCurrentField instanceof TabFieldItem) {
            return ((TabFieldItem) mCurrentField).keyChar(ch, status, time);
        } else {
            return super.keyChar(ch, status, time);
        }
    }
}
```

**TabFieldItem.java**

```java
package com.np.custom;

public interface TabFieldItem {
    /**
     * Method invoked when the tabField is about to be displayed
     */
    public void onSelected();

    /**
     * Method invoked when the tabField is about to be removed from the display
     */
    public void onUnSelected();

    public boolean keyChar(char ch, int status, int time);

}
```

I have used the sublyout method in TabField.java class.
and the result is as shown in the image.

[image]

Comment: This link will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942225/tab-bar-in-blackberry-without-toolbarmanager/8967671#8967671

Comment: if you observe the flow no need any suggestion;

Comment: Actually its not working. I am still at the same place from where I started. I need tabs at the bottom of the field.:(

Comment: if you are using my code, did you put this statement :"bottomPanel=new BottomPanel(current_index);
setStatus(bottomPanel);" in your code?

Comment: Ur code is not working dear, I can just see a blank white screen after debugging I get to know that craeteGUI method is calling initially.:(
Please update me with some changes if i need to perform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a manager above the 'add(mTabController)' and put fixed height of that manager overriding sublayout & set setextent inside sublayout, height must be displayheight-mtabcontroller height. And remove the sublayout what overridden in tabfield class.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [setStatus(mTabField)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/MainScreen.html#setStatus%28net.rim.device.api.ui.Field%29) instead of overriding sublayout.

Comment: Hello ajmal, setStutus(mTabField) is also a good option but this option will not provide to the methods implementations like selection() and Unselection() which are very useful for a big application.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few recommendations I'd have.

First, when building stuff like this, especially for BlackBerry, it can be really difficult to get all the click handling, or focus handling correct.  It's usually a good idea to start with one of RIM's examples, that you know works.  In this case, you can [see their Tab Bar example here](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800508/How_To_-_Create_tabbed_view_screens.html?nodeid=1357482&vernum=0).

If you want to stick with your code, there's a couple things I see that might be problems:

```java
//SUBLAYOUT METHOD USED TO BRING THE TABBAR AT THE BOTTOM OF THE SCREEN---------------
protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
    super.sublayout(maxWidth, maxHeight);
    tabHieght = mTabController.getHeight();
    int y = displayHieght - tabHieght;
    setPositionChild(mTabController, 0, y);
}
```

1. When you implement `sublayout()`, you should usually be calling `setPositionChild()` and `layoutChild()` for each child field that your `Manager` has.  You are only calling `setPositionChild()`.  Frequently, calling `setExtent()` is also appropriate.
2. I have seen a bunch of problems recently where people override `VerticalFieldManager` (or `HorizontalFieldManager`) and then still override `sublayout()` to provide custom layout management.  That defeats the purpose of using `VerticalFieldManager` in the first place, since it performs a vertical layout for you, laying out child fields in the order that you `add()` them.  If you want any customization, I would recommend extending `Manager`, and not `VerticalFieldManager`.  If the default `VerticalFieldManager` layout isn't what you want, then just provide the full implementation that `Manager` requires.  It's not very difficult.  Just implement `sublayout()`, `getPreferredWidth()` and `getPreferredHeight()`.

Of course, you still need to implement `sublayout()` correctly (see **1.** above).

Anyway, the other people who posted similar problems were also seeing strange behavior until they changed their class (`TabField` for you) to `extends Manager`.  That's what I would try fixing first.

Answer (score 0):

For tab bar example,  Make new Project in Blackberry JDE (4.5 and above)

Just Copy below code and execute it.

**MyTabAppDemo.java**

```
package com.app;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;

public class MyTabAppDemo extends UiApplication
{   public static void main(String[] args)
    {   MyApp theApp = new MyApp();       
        theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
    }
    public MyApp()
    {             
        pushScreen(new TabScreenExample());
    }    
}
```

**TabScreenExample.java**

```
package com.app;

import net.rim.device.api.system.Application;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Display;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager;

public class TabScreenExample extends MainScreen {
    private VerticalFieldManager mainManager;
    private NavigationMenuBar tabBar;

    public TabScreenExample() {
        tabBar = new NavigationMenuBar() {

            public void onNavigationClick(int selection) {
                if (NavigationMenuBar.TAB1 == selection) {
                    // Push Screen Which is releted to first tab
                    synchronized (Application.getEventLock()) {
                        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new Screan1());
                    }
                } else if (NavigationMenuBar.TAB2 == selection) {
                    // Push Screen Which is releted to second tab
                    synchronized (Application.getEventLock()) {
                        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new Screan2());
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        mainManager = new VerticalFieldManager() {
            protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                super.sublayout(maxWidth, maxHeight);
                setExtent(getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
            }

            public int getPreferredWidth() {
                return Display.getWidth();
            }

            public int getPreferredHeight() {
                return Display.getHeight() - tabBar.getPreferredHeight();
            }
        };

        add(mainManager);
        add(tabBar);
    }
}
```

// Here is Custom tab bar.. in this tab bar you can add many tabs.

**NavigationMenuBar.java**

```
package com.app;

import net.rim.device.api.system.Application;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Display;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.KeypadUtil;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.HorizontalFieldManager;

public abstract class NavigationMenuBar extends HorizontalFieldManager {

    public static final int TAB1 = 0;
    public static final int TAB2 = 1;

    // Create object of tabs
    private TopBarComponenet tab1;
    private TopBarComponenet tab2;

    // Selected Tab;
    private int currentState;

    // tab Normal Image
    private Bitmap imgTab1Normal, imgTab2Normal;

    // tab Focus Image
    private Bitmap imgTab1Focus, imgTab2Focus;

    public NavigationMenuBar() {

        // Normal Images
        imgTab1Normal = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("tab1Normal.png");
        imgTab2Normal = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("tab2Normal.png");

        // Focus Images
        imgTab1Focus = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("tab1Focus.png");
        imgTab2Focus = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("tab2Focus.png");

        // create first tab
        tab1 = new TopBarComponenet(imgTab1Normal) {

            protected void onClick() {
                currentState = TAB1;
                selectTab(currentState);
            }
        };
        // create Second tab
        tab2 = new TopBarComponenet(imgTab2Normal) {

            protected void onClick() {
                currentState = TAB2;
                selectTab(currentState);
            }
        };

        // add tab button in horizontal manager.
        add(tab1);
        add(tab2);
    }

    public int getPreferredHeight() {
        return imgTab1Normal.getHeight();
    }

    public void selectTab(int tab) {
        synchronized (Application.getEventLock()) {
            // Set Tab visible GUI
            if (tab == TAB1) {
                tab1.setFocus();
                tab1.setBgImage(imgTab1Focus);
                tab2.setBgImage(imgTab2Normal);
                tab1.selected = true;
                tab2.selected = false;
            } else if (tab == TAB2) {
                tab2.setFocus();
                tab1.setBgImage(imgTab1Normal);
                tab2.setBgImage(imgTab2Focus);
                tab1.selected = false;
                tab2.selected = true;
            }
        }
        currentState = tab;
        onNavigationClick(currentState);
    }

    public void deselectAllTab() {
        tab1.setBgImage(imgTab1Normal);
        tab2.setBgImage(imgTab2Normal);
        tab1.selected = false;
        tab2.selected = false;
    }

    public abstract void onNavigationClick(int selection);

    protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
        super.sublayout(maxWidth, maxHeight);
        setExtent(Display.getWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
    }

    protected void paintBackground(Graphics gr) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.paintBackground(gr);
        gr.setColor(0x000000);
        gr.fillRect(0, 0, Display.getWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
    }

    private abstract class TopBarComponenet extends Field {

        private Bitmap bgImage;
        private String text;
        public boolean selected;
        private int width;
        private int height;

        public TopBarComponenet(final Bitmap bgImage) {
            super(FOCUSABLE);
            this.bgImage = bgImage;
            // this width depends on how many tab added.
            // for example if we want to add 5 tab then
            // width = Display.getWidth() / 5;
            width = Display.getWidth() / 2;
            height = bgImage.getHeight();
        }

        public void setBgImage(Bitmap image) {
            this.bgImage = image;
        }

        protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on) {
        }

        protected void layout(int width, int height) {
            setExtent(getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
        }

        public int getPreferredHeight() {
            return height;
        }

        public int getPreferredWidth() {
            return width;
        }

        protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
            graphics.drawBitmap((width - bgImage.getWidth()) / 2, 0,
                    bgImage.getWidth(), bgImage.getHeight(), bgImage, 0, 0);
            if (isFocus()) {
                graphics.setColor(0xffffff); // white
                graphics.setGlobalAlpha(50);
                graphics.fillRoundRect(0, 2, width, height - 4, 10, 10);
                graphics.setGlobalAlpha(255);
            }
        }

        protected void onFocus(int direction) {
            super.onFocus(direction);
            invalidate();
        }

        protected void onUnfocus() {
            super.onUnfocus();
            invalidate();
        }

        protected boolean keyDown(int keycode, int time) {
            char c = KeypadUtil.getKeyChar(keycode,
                    KeypadUtil.MODE_UI_CURRENT_LOCALE);
            if (c == '\n') {
                onClick();
            } else if (keycode == 13) {
                onClick();
            }
            return super.keyDown(keycode, time);
        }

        protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
            onClick();
            return true;
        }

        protected abstract void onClick();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Krishna Kant Sir, thanks a ton for answering my query but its not what i am actually looking for.
Tabbar must visible when we click on any Tab, it must not move to background.
Can we do like all time visible tabs in the whole app.
Again thanks for providing for your value time and suggestion, and I am still looking for the suggestion that will actually fulfil my requirements...... 

I already worked on Tabs using MANAGERS as shown above, but the major problem is "TO BRING THEM AT THE BOTTOM OF THE SCREEN".

Answer (score 0):

Screen1.java

```
    package com.app;

        import net.rim.device.api.system.Application;
        import net.rim.device.api.system.Display;
        import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
        import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField;
        import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
        import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager;

        public class Screen1 extends MainScreen {
            private VerticalFieldManager mainManager;
            private NavigationMenuBar tabBar;
        private static Screen1 ref= null;

    public static Screen1 getInstance(){
        if(ref==null){
            ref = new Screen1();
        }
        return ref;
    }
            public Screen1() {
                tabBar = new NavigationMenuBar() {

                    public void onNavigationClick(int selection) {
                        if (NavigationMenuBar.TAB1 == selection) {

                        } else if (NavigationMenuBar.TAB2 == selection) {
                            // Push Screen Which is releted to second tab
                            synchronized (Application.getEventLock()) {
                                Screen2.getInstance().setSelectedTab(NavigationMenuBar.TAB2);
                        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(
                                Screen2.getInstance());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
                tabBar.selectTab(NavigationMenuBar.TAB1);
                mainManager = new VerticalFieldManager() {
                    protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                        super.sublayout(maxWidth, maxHeight);
                        setExtent(getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
                    }

                    public int getPreferredWidth() {
                        return Display.getWidth();
                    }

                    public int getPreferredHeight() {
                        return Display.getHeight() - tabBar.getPreferredHeight();
                    }
                };
        //      setTitle("Screen one");
                mainManager.add(new ButtonField("Screen1"));

                add(mainManager);
                add(tabBar);
            }
public void setSelectedTab(int tabNumber) {
    tabBar.selectTab(tabNumber);
}
        }
```

SCreen2.java

```
 package com.app;

    import net.rim.device.api.system.Application;
    import net.rim.device.api.system.Display;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager;

    public class Screen2 extends MainScreen {
        private VerticalFieldManager mainManager;
        private NavigationMenuBar tabBar;
    private static Screen2 ref= null;

    public static Screen2 getInstance(){
        if(ref==null){
            ref = new Screen2();
        }
        return ref;
    }
        public Screen2() {
            tabBar = new NavigationMenuBar() {

                public void onNavigationClick(int selection) {
                    if (NavigationMenuBar.TAB1 == selection) {
                        // Push Screen Which is releted to first tab
                        synchronized (Application.getEventLock()) {
                            Screen1.getInstance().setSelectedTab(NavigationMenuBar.TAB1);
                        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(
                                Screen1.getInstance());
                        }
                    } else if (NavigationMenuBar.TAB2 == selection) {

                    }
                }
            };
            tabBar.selectTab(NavigationMenuBar.TAB2);
            mainManager = new VerticalFieldManager() {
                protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                    super.sublayout(maxWidth, maxHeight);
                    setExtent(getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
                }

                public int getPreferredWidth() {
                    return Display.getWidth();
                }

                public int getPreferredHeight() {
                    return Display.getHeight() - tabBar.getPreferredHeight();
                }
            };
    //      setTitle("Screen two");
            mainManager.add(new ButtonField("Screen2"));
            add(mainManager);
            add(tabBar);
        }
public void setSelectedTab(int tabNumber) {
    tabBar.selectTab(tabNumber);
}
    }
```

and please comment these two lines in NAvigationMenuScreen

tab1.setFocus();

tab2.setFocus();

Comment: Hello sir, the code looks like working, gives best UI features but if you looks to the functionality, like If I click on Tab1 it creates 1 instance of Class Screen1 and than I click on Tab2 than it creates an instance of Class Screen2 NOW when I come back to Tab1 than it just creates a new instance of Class Screen1. Same will happen if I click on Tab2. This will not be feasible as the main functionality of tabs are to save its state when we switch from 1 tab to another tab.

Comment: I am very thankful that you are providing your precious time, I need to solve the issues and generate the base of my app as soon as possible please suggest me.:(

Comment: please create screen1 and screen2 as a singleton class. i edit screen 1.java and screen2.java please check it.

Comment: I have copied the two class as it is Screen1 and Screen2 as it is, and make two changes in the TabScreenExample Class from where I have to initially pushscreen screen1 and screen2 instances. 
Still getting RunTimeException related to UI on NavigationClick when click on Tab1 second time.:(
I am following exactly as instructed but still its not working for me.:(

Comment: I have done with what I required, by using Custom TabControl using VERTICAL and HORIZONTAL field manager. Its working very efficiently as I am using the code in moving within 3 levels from parent to child classes in each tab.
Home tab (Class A -> ClassB -> Class C) even viceversa using back key.
Thanx to all for a huge support.